# ¿Expresión regular para montos en flutter?

Tags: regex, flutter

Estoy buscando hacer una **expresión regular** para validar los montos ingresados.

Pero no encuentro la manera de hacer que la misma logre alterar el monto ingresado, quiero decir, sí ingreso `100000` necesito que la expresión regular le ponga el separador de miles y decimales para que quede así => `100.000,00` y de igual manera para los millones `1000000` => `1.000.000,00`

De momento solo tengo esta expresión regular

```
r'^(\d{1}\.)?(\d+\.?)+(,\d{2})?$'
```

Agradecería su ayuda, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Opción 1:

Crear una `function` que:

- Convierta el numero a cadena.
- Separe en partes (*entera y decimal*) la cadena.
- Utilice una `RegExp` para formatear solo la parte entera.
- Valide que la parte decimal exista y complete con 2 decimales.

#### Ejemplo:

```
String numberFormat(double x) {
  List<String> parts = x.toString().split('.');
  RegExp re = RegExp(r'\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))');

  parts[0] = parts[0].replaceAll(re, '.');
  if (parts.length == 1) {
    parts.add('00');
  } else {
    parts[1] = parts[1].padRight(2, '0').substring(0, 2);
  }
  return parts.join(',');
}

double value = 1000000;
print(numberFormat(value));
=> 1.000.000,00
```

---

### Opción 2:

Podrías agregar a tu proyecto el paquete [`intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) y utilizar la clase [`NumberFormat`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl#number-formatting-and-parsing)

#### Ejemplo

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

NumberFormat f = new NumberFormat("#,##0.00", "es_AR");
print(f.format(1000000));
=> 1.000.000,00
```

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta aceptada esta bien pero mal formulada, si se usa el valor `es_AR` sale como resultado el punto para separar miles y la coma para decimales lo cual esta mal, segun la documentacion de `NumberFormat`

> https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html

patrones de formato de la UCI.

`.` Separador decimal

`,` Separador de agrupación

Por lo cual se debe usar la coma para separar agrupacion y no el punto por lo tanto se debe usar `es_US`

**Por acá mi función**

```
String expresionRegular(double numero){
  NumberFormat f = new NumberFormat("#,###.0#", "es_US");
  String result = f.format(numero);
  return result;
}
```